# Prohibitions on Brahmins regarding reading Bhagavad Gita

Tags: bhagavad-gita, brahmins

Why Hindu Brahmins were not allowed by other castes,which includes Kayasthas to read BHAGVAD GITA and were  (discouraged by Hindu Bramhan Gurus also}during a distinct period of history?  Is there any specific reason?

Comment: I have never heard of such rule or restriction. In my place, it' Brahmins who recite it and explain to others. Scriptural rules indicate same. Can you specify where you have heard or seen such restriction?

Comment: Please don't edit the question once it has been answered. Otherwise the answer becomes out of sync with question and confuses future readers. Also, bounty reason ("What duties make Hindu brahmins separate from other castes? Just like rules are amended, many amendments are made by maharishis. When the last updating was done which are acceptable?") is very different from the original question. So it's likely your bounty will be canceled. You need to ask a separate question about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **no such restrictions** whatsoever. Krishna DvaipAyana VyAsa (also known as Veda VyAsa) was a Maharshi & son of a Brahmana named ParAshara. Sage VyAsa himself had passed on Gita (as part of Mahabharata) to his [supposed] Brahmana disciples.

Moreover, with the context of *Moksha* and *Dharma*, Shri Krishna declares that the study of Gita (learning or hearing) with faith, is virtuous:

> BG 18.70 - And **those who will study this sacred conversation between us two,** which is conducive to virtue, by him I shall be adored through the Sacrifice in the form of Knowledge. **This is My judgement.**.
>   BG 18.71 - Any man who, being reverential and free from cavilling, might even hear (this), he too, becoming free, shall attain the blessed worlds of those who perform virtuous deeds.
>   <sub>tr. Gambhirananda</sub>